# NGINX invalid port in upstream

Tags: nginx, proxy, port

I am using nginx as a proxy to a nodejs application.  I have the same application running multiple times each on a different port.  The request is directed to the correct application/port based on host name.

```
So   
test1.domain.com   would be proxied to 127.0.0.1:8000
test2.domain.com   would be proxied to 127.0.0.1:8001
test3.domain.com   would be proxied to 127.0.0.1:8002
```

When I hard code " proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8000;"  Everything works fine.

Now I wrote a njs script to read a file in a users directory to get the port number based on the subdommain.  Here is the script.

```
#inclusion of js file
js_include sites-available/port_assign.js;
js_set $myPort port;

    function port(r) {
        var host = r.headersIn.host;
        var subdomain = host.split('.');
        var fs = require('fs');
        var filename = '/home/' + subdomain[0] + '/port';
        var port = fs.readFileSync(filename);
        port.trim();
        return(port);
}
```

this does read the file and  returns the port number correctly. I have verified this in the error logs, Because I get:

```
2020/01/21 04:26:46 [error] 2729#2729: *6 invalid port in upstream "127.0.0.1:8001
", client: 96.54.17.234, server: *.foundryserver.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "test1.foundryserver.com"
```

now when I tried to issue the directive:  proxy_pass     http://127.0.0.1:$myPort  I get an internal server error and the error stated above.

Not sure what is the difference it the two.  I can only think somehow using a variable $myPort is got weird characters or something.

Comment: It's difficult to tell, but is there some white space between the `8001` and the closing `"`?

Answer (score 0):

There was some extra information in the port variable.  I was able to store the port number in a json format and parse it in the js.  {"port":"8000"} is stored in the file.

```
function port(r) {
        var host = r.headersIn.host;
        var subdomain = host.split('.');
        var fs = require('fs');
        var filename = '/home/' + subdomain[0] + '/myport';
        var jport = fs.readFileSync(filename);
        var port = JSON.parse(jport);
        return(port.port);
}
```

by doing the json parsing it removed any unseen characters in the variable.